# Jpa self join performance issue

Tags: performance, jpa

I have implemented jpa self join relationship in one of my project. We have  more than 200k records in this table. I am also using delete orphan annotation. Now when my app tries to delete orphaned entities which has this self join then it is taking too long to delete records in db. Our dba check index and everything else.

Can someone please explain what can cause this performance issue? Looking at the query, I believe it is scanning whole table to verify parent child relation before deleting those records.

Answer (score 0):

For huge tables and self join, usually the simple join queries generated by ORM  tools are not performant. To confirm you can log the sql produced by the ORM and then run `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR` or `EXPLAIN` (depending upon whether the database is oracle or mysql) and analyse the output. This would give you a fair idea of what is wrong.You might need to actually write an an alternate SQL query and tune it and then use NativeQuery feature of JPA to get the query result effectively.

Comment: So do you recommend to delete orphaned records by using native query?